# Toast: Difference between "this" and "getApplicationContext()"?

Tags: android, android-context, android-toast, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My device runs Android 5.1.1 and I found out that if I use

```
Toast.makeText(this, "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I got this:

[image: "round" toast]

But if I use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I got this:

[image: rectangle toast]

Both are called directly from the activity.

Why is this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to do with the Theme the Context has associated with it.  Using `this` is using a context (I'm assuming your `Activity` or `Fragment`) that has a different theme than the Application Context.

If you have a reason you need to be using the application context, you can wrap it in whichever theme your activities are using (usually set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`) and it should show the "round" toast.

```
Toast.makeText(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme), "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```