# Android TextView created dynamically becomes gray

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

So I have a `LinearLayout` then inside is a `ScrollView` then inside is another `RelativeLayout` and finally inside is another `LinearLayout` with id `mylinearlayout`.

I want to create `TextView's` dynamically it works fine, but the text seems to be disabled like `GRAY` color. Although i didn't set any color..
Here's my code:

```
final LinearLayout linlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());                          
tv.setTextSize(20);
tv.isEnabled();
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
if(orderstatus.equals("Pending")) {
    tv.setText("OrderID: "+orderid + "\n"+"OrderDate: " + orderdate + "\n"  +"OrderStatus: "+orderstatus + " \n\n");
    tv.setId(i + 5);
    linlayout.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: why don't you just set the color for it?

Comment: i tried it but no changes at all, I even tried to change it to red but still gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this code

```
linlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setTextSize(20);
tv.isEnabled();
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
if(orderstatus.equals("Pending"))
{
tv.setText("OrderID: "+orderid + "\n"+"OrderDate: " + orderdate + "\n"  +"OrderStatus: "+orderstatus + " \n\n");
tv.setId(i + 5);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
linlayout.addView(tv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing well, but miss one moment. When you add view into layout, view automaticly sets color from current system styles. If you need to change color of your text, do this:

```
tv.setTextColor(YOUR_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` text may grey because it's using the system `Theme` rather than your `Activity`'s. You could try passing `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in your `TextView()` constructor. This is true for [Toast objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045471/toast-difference-between-this-and-getapplicationcontext/33045542), for example, and may also apply to widgets.

Comment: thanks for the reply but when I use 'this' i get undefined error and when i use getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme i also get error